# Path to find my.cnf file in XAMPP and PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to update the field but I am getting the error. I am using XAMPP and PHPMyAdmin.

```
 Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute(): MySQL server has gone away in 
 C:\xampp\htdocs\get_content\process.php on line 159

 Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute(): Error reading result set's header in
 C:\xampp\htdocs\get_content\process.php on line 159
```

I know I have to check the `max_allowed_packet` in the `my.cnf`  MySQL config file but I am not getting `my.cnf` file.

I checked

```
C:\xampp\mysql
C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin
C:\xampp\php
C:\Windows
C:\Program Files (x86)
```

but I haven't found. I found the below path on google but this is also I am not able to find.

```
/etc/my.cnf
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
/usr/etc/my.cnf
```

Can anyone share me the whole path to resolve my issue?

Comment: Check `C:\xampp\mysql\bin`, that should be the default location AFAIK.

Comment: @CBroe, I just want to know my.cnf and my.ini both file are same?

Comment: Because I haven't got my.cnf but I got my.ini file in the bin folder.

Comment: `my.ini` === `my.cnf`

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/my-cnf-or-is-it-my-ini/4266/3

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks, I update the packet file and it's working.